# Gradle - Mutiple Dependencies for Java Project

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Just started tying to use gradle, but not getting far. Please help.

I've followed the documentation, but it only show single dependencies or dependencies that I can't get to work. Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
OFFICEDB_VERSION = 'JAN12R2'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group:
            'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.0.Alpha1',
            'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Alpha1',
            'com.exlogs.officedb:common:${OFFICEDB_VERSION}',
            'com.exlogs.officedb:officedb-service:${OFFICEDB_VERSION}',
            'com.exlogs:eventhub:1.0.0-RC1',
            'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'

testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

The problem is when I type in `gradle build` on the command line I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Dev\Code\officedb\manpower\build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'manpower'.
> Could not create a dependency using notation: {group=org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.0.Alpha1}
```

But looking at the documentation this should be fine. Also all the example build files I've found are rather small or only have a single dependency. Does anyone have any views about using gradle for large commercial projects.

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify configuration (similar to Maven scope, i.e. `compile`, `testCompile`, etc) for each dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.0.Alpha1'
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Alpha1'
    compile "com.exlogs.officedb:common:${OFFICEDB_VERSION}"
    compile "com.exlogs.officedb:officedb-service:${OFFICEDB_VERSION}"
    compile 'com.exlogs:eventhub:1.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.0'
}
```

`group` is a part of alternative syntax to provide dependency coordinates (`group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'`), not a special keyword.

Also note that you need double quotes to use variables in strings:

```
compile "com.exlogs.officedb:common:${OFFICEDB_VERSION}"
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but after spending a couple of hours trying to get it to work I still get `Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.` Even though I've lifted the dependencies straight from a build.xml file that works. Given the lack of clear documentation I don't think gradle is ready for main stream. Going back to Maven - not great, but it does work out of the box and the documentation is comprehensive and well explained.

Comment: Hey Adam, Gradle is used in big mission critical environments and the userguide includes more than 300 pages so I can't understand your arguments here. Can you post the stack trace running your build with the "-i" option? maybe we can figure out why your build is failing

Comment: Thanks Rene, I will post it, but I'll have to wait until monday GMT now.

Comment: My guess would be that your com.exlogs.officedb dependencies don't live in mavenCentral, but rather in mavenLocal(), or some private maven repository. Add those to the repositories configuration...

Comment: Chaps, I like Gradle, or at least the idea of it, but I don't quite understand the philosophy of its implementation. For example, why do you have to put parametrized dependencies in "" rather than ''. Why when "creating properties on demand" has been deprecated is there are no examples or explanations of how alternative method for defining properties used for version numbers?  Why does Gradle not use the local maven repository as default just as Maven does, even when you use mavenCentral(), it must download to a local repo(???). Does Gradle support reports like you get in the Maven Site phase?

Comment: ad 1. This is just the way Groovy works. ad 2. See "extra properties" in the user guide. ad 3. Gradle is its own build system with its own cache (which provides unique features). ad 4. Not yet, but it is in the works.